# Is it possible to install OS during RAID scrubbing?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hardware-raid, raid5

One of our servers crashed a few days ago. I had to recreate the RAID container with the remaining disks. Currently the system is running the scrubbing process (screenshot below). I would like to know if its okay to proceed with attempting to install the OS or is it imperative to wait until the process completes before doing anything else.

Please see the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When the server boots, sure, why not...  it may be slower though.

Comment: Ahhh....what screen shots

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know if its okay to proceed with attempting to install
>   the OS or is it imperative to wait until the process completes before
>   doing anything else.

Yes, you can use the server as you normally would. The only symptom will be slightly decreased IO performance until the RAID scrub completes.

If it were possible to corrupt data during this sort of operation, any decent controller would not permit you to exit out of the RAID utility or would pause the boot process until the operation completes.

Comment: Is it okay to do a format or a quick format?

Comment: Read my answer. You can use the server as you normally would.

Comment: Now, I have installed the OS and made the container bootable too but still its not going to the OS.

Comment: Well that's a completely separate problem.

Comment: Do you have any workarounds for that?

Comment: That is a separate question. Please submit it as such, not a comment.